# file output formatting with spaces unix

Tags: unix, awk, formatting, text-processing

This is what the original file looks like

```
cat new

Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as
Filer, Jack C0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab
Metro, Jim K. C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

I am having an issue formatting this file for names that don't have a middle name.

```
$ cat new | awk '{printf "%10s %7s %3s %6s %7s %6s %6s %4s %6s\n" $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}'

Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book   pizza apple 4.00 123as
Filer, Jack C0002 happy  apple hat   4.00 124ab
Metro, Jim K.   C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

Now thats what the format comes out as what I would like it to be is each column to be spaced 1 space a part so like the name is Jackson, Bob D. is a column c0001 is a column now the name has spaces in between each letter.  The problem is people without middle names is messing everything up how can i format this file to look like this

```
Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book   pizza apple 4.00 123as
Filer, Jack     C0002 happy  apple hat   4.00 124ab
Metro, Jim K.   C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

So everything lines up and looks clean any questions let me know thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Please show the sample input file you used to produce this.

Comment: You assign only three characters to the name, why you expect it to have a width more than that?

Comment: No he assigns 10 to the name @pfnuesel; 3 is the number.

Comment: No the issue isnt that i am missing characters what its doing is when people dont have middle letter it pulls the next column so C0002 is trying to print where the middle name is if that makes sense what i am trying to do is seperate each column clearly so that thoughs without middle names dont mess it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS='~' '{$2=$2" "$3;$3=""} 
            NF==10{$2=$2" "$4;$4=""} 
             NF==9{$3=$3 OFS ""}1' file | column -ts~

1  Jackson, Bob D.  C0001  book    pizza  apple  4.00  123as
2  Filer, Jack      C0002  happy   apple  hat    4.00  124ab
3  Metro, Jim K.    C0003  kindle  pizza  grape  4.00  125ac
```

you can shift the fields in `awk` as an alternative solution but this works as well.

set output field separator (OFS) to some unused char (here tilde) and let `column` handled the formatting by that delimiter.

Comment: Ok I had a mistake in the original file content I was looking at one i was trying to format does the way i have it set now affect this? cause its still trying to pull c0002 as the middle name and not sure why

Comment: Shift all fields by one. $2->$1 etc. also conditions need to be decremented by one.

Comment: sorry not to good with this command OFS what do we decremented? little new to awk still sorry for the confusion

Comment: is there any way to save this new output into a file? or a variable without losing what we just did?

Comment: just add `> outputfilename` at the end.

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's already left aligned.  Replace `1`  with block `{printf "% ... ", $1, $2, ...}`

Comment: Ok one last thing now is there anyway to take and be able to left align text like for example awk {printf "%-3s", $1} is how i would do it normally but im trying to figure out a way to take what we had and still use awk to format it further is this possible? or using something like awk 'BEGIN {pattern} {printf "%-3s," $1; next} now there will definitely be more to this awk but im just curious if it possible to add more formatting once i am able to use OFS? like possible all in one statement? sorry for some many questions